# Recursions to produce the prime numbers in Python 2

Tags: python, recursion, primes, nonetype

I was trying to use a recursion to produce the prime numbers in python (because I found that an iterative approach would take too much time, especially if say one wants to find all the prime numbers up to a number like 1 million or so). This is my code:

```
def primes(n): #to produce prime numbers less than or equal to n
    if n <= 1:
        return "No primes that satisfy"
    elif n == 2:
        return [2]
    else:
        if all(n%a != 0 for a in primes(n-1)): #A number, n, must not be divisible by any of the prime numbers contained in the list primes(n-1)
          k = primes(n-1).append(n)
          return k
        else:
          S = primes(n-1)
          S = primes(n)
          return S
print primes(5)
```

I am getting the following error- TypeError:'NoneType' object is not iterable. I am only a beginner in Python and I am not sure what this means. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point out why this error originates and what improvements I may be able to make to the program to avoid this error.
Thank you

Comment: I realise that I have not declared primes(n) in the "if all" part of the code. However, if I put " k = primes(n)", I run into a "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" and also the problem of assigning a value to a function-call.

Comment: This recursive algorithm seems to grow exponentially in time. For me, primes(15) takes .02s, primes(20) takes .2s, and primes(25) takes 6.4s. So each +5 takes at least *10 longer.  FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: So it would seem that the Sieve of Eratosthenes would be the best way to generate prime numbers?

Comment: Definitely, old good method, even little improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this program fragment:

```
k = primes(n-1).append(n)
return k
```

The return value from `list.append()` is `None`, so `k = None`, and you  effectively perform `return None`.

Try this:

```
k = primes(n-1) + [n]
```

Aside: OP has at least one other bug. They need to delete the line `S = primes(n)`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Yes, this method does work, but for small values of n, such as n = 3. When I test "primes(5)", it runs into a runtime error: "Maximum recursion depth exceeded". Is there any way by which I can avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: Fix your other bug. Delete the line `S = primes(n)`